# HQL Object set from set

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I got a `Set<UserDTO>` collection in a not Hibernate object, and I got a `User` domain entity in Hibernate.

`UserDTO` contains less information about user (only id and name)

How can I select full Hibernate User `Set`/`List` from the DTO object?

Like this?

```
Set<UserDTO> setDTO = .....
String hql = "FROM User WHERE id IN (:userDTO )";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql); 
query.setParameter("userDTO", setDTO);
return query.getResultList();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. But you'd have to extract the IDs in a separate collection first:

```
Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>(setDTO.size());
for (UserDTO dto : setDTO) {
   ids.add(dto.getId());
}
```

Then proceed with the query, and pass the `ids` set as param.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you need to use Query#setParameterList() instead of Query#setParameter.

Comment: it will work either way, I think. though if you know it's a list (it's a `Set` in this case), you should use the more specific method

Comment: Possibly. I seem to remember struggling to use a Collection in the setParameter. And yep setParameterList in actual fact takes a Collection!

Comment: I just tried writing a test for each method and if you pass a List<String> to setParameter you get a ClassCastException when the query is executed.

Comment: hm, perhaps you are right. Or it is not consistent across versions

Comment: Quite possibly, this experiment was only for 3.6.7! There are many more out there!